# Optionality of argument of child one function depend on optionality of argument of other function typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading, conditional-types

I am creating a function example, which takes function fn1 as an argument and returns function fn2;

```
type Values<T> = (values: T) => Promise<void>;  //function with argument
type NoValues = () => Promise<void>;    //function without arguments
type Func1<T> = Values<T> | NoValues;

let example = function <T, R extends Func1<T> = Func1<T>>(fn1: R) {  
    const fn2 = async (values: R extends Values<T> ? T : void) => { 
        await fn1(values);
    }
    return fn2;
}
```

fn1 should take one optional argument. Depending on whether fn1 has optional argument, fn2 also should have it. So if fn1 DOES NOT have any arguments, then fn2 should also not have them and vice-versa.

I tried to write such restrictions with many ways, but still can not succeed. I would be glad if someone helps me.

```
interface IExample {
    whatever: string;
}
const test1_fn1 = async () => console.log("");
const test1_fn2 = example<IExample>(test1_fn1);
test1_fn2() //Should work, but does not. Expected 1 argument. Not intended

const test2_fn1 = async (values: IExample) => console.log(values);
const test2_fn2 = example<IExample>(test2_fn1);
test2_fn2() //Should not work, does not work, as intended
test2_fn2({whatever: ""}) //Should work, works, as intended
```

TS version: 3.8.3.
Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA%20KBeKACgDdEVUAuKTASn1wAUAnAewFsBLVCdYljgCbYA3FCgB6cQDMkAOwDGwDi1lQA7h2AALKHCYBzJGwizgAKFCQoAORbxkafETp5GrTt178hosROlyisqqGtosSMC6BkYmwKgW4NAAYoEAjFi4BPbkGVAAPjZ2ZGjCZmYIEJEQAB5wbGAVTjIKSipQWAA0UABKUDXAJgKoUCkK6ThOo-Lj2NiEUrKpVN10AN5iZn5Q8iqokQsATE5wqCAKRKQOlD191QOyQ7DFGBMA-NRQVHyCLrjrm1s-HA1HBNFAFqkSM8aKUtgBfAFiJiVJBMVSHUoIswcUwQJhSODyaAASQAorV6o1Voj1Fo4ANiHiqHsmDj9JiyjtZHsoAM9qkAPoQ46nc6EX7bXYsCoAOgQLH0hAAREqYWYuTy%20cBBYcnDU6g0eGSKYa5lqdYs1eahbIDuL-ABlLThBACdQsJgAay6ACMIlABCxHLIWMAZVByZBFBA3akooZjKZw7ZIjj7gIY5zdpEtQcbXGCCczvILs8qMaDRUJRrpRA5QqoVc1Rqc2hgHndQR9ZSjeTKxAzW2O5bSrmbXa6JInS63SHImoPd6A0HhnP3V6uicoGnBpmx4dCKs1HSGUyoCq4ZPxNOkK710uF17UJvhjuHpmgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest with overloading:

```
type Values<T> = (values: T) => Promise<void>;  //function with argument
type NoValues = () => Promise<void>;    //function without arguments
type Func1<T> = Values<T> | NoValues;

function makeFn2<T>(fn1: NoValues): NoValues;
function makeFn2<T>(fn1: Values<T>): Values<T>;
function makeFn2<T>(fn1: Func1<T>): Func1<T> {  
    return async (...values: [T?]) => { 
        await (fn1 as any)(...values);
    }
}


declare const argFunc: Values<string>;
const argFunc2=makeFn2(argFunc);
argFunc2("s");
argFunc2();  // error

declare const noArgFunc: NoValues;
const noArgFunc2=makeFn2(noArgFunc);
noArgFunc2();
noArgFunc2("asd");  // error
```

It should be correct both in compilation and in runtime, i.e. fn1 is called with an argument only if fn2 was called with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is what I needed. Don't you know how to make the same behaviour using conditional types and without using overloading. I just spent a lot of time trying to solve it this way, and would be happy to look what I did wrong.

Comment: @TimurRakhimzhan I added an option without overloads, but I think the overload is nicer.

Comment: The solution without overloading unfortunately does not work. I tried it in playground. Can you update your answer? @TPReal

Comment: @TimurRakhimzhan Sorry, my mistake. Looks like I can't really do this in any reasonable way. It's possible to declare `function makeFn2<T, F extends Func1<T>>(fn1: F): F extends NoValues ? NoValues : Values<T>` but then you need to call `makeFn2<string,Values<string>>(argFunc)`, so it's not worth it. The overload is a good solution.